# PHP ZipArchive not unzipping on CentOS 4.8

Tags: php, centos

I've been doing some work with PHPs ZipArchive. On my local windows machine using WAMP I am able to select a zip file, upload and unzip to my desired destination.

When I attempt to do the same on a CentOS server, the .zip file is uploaded to my desired destination but is not being unzipped.

I've done some research and see that ZipArchive is only available if PHP is compiled with --enable-zip. If this was the case, shouldn't the upload fail? I don't understand why the .zip file is still being placed in my desired destination.

Comment: Anything in your logs? Are you displaying errors or warnings?

Comment: The act of uploading a file is entirely different than the act of working with the file.  Without seeing the code involved, we have no way of truly telling you where your error is.

Answer (score 0):

I did a class_exists(ZipArchive) and it returned false on the CentOS server. I find it weird the file is still uploaded but now I know why it isn't working.

Thanks anyways.